# Unexpected blank output in c

Tags: c, error-handling

I'm a pseudo programmer that is having such a bad time with empty terminal outputs in c language... this isn't the first time I got this issue, so I kindly as for some experienced mind to gimme a hand and analyze this code, to see whether if I'm dumb, or if I got a compiler problem or idk what...

well the code is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

char PalindromeCheck (int number){
   int NumCopy = number;
   while (NumCopy != 0){
      int LastDigit = NumCopy % 10;
      NumCopy = NumCopy / 10;
      if (LastDigit != NumCopy % 10){
         return "Not a Palindrome";
      }
   }
   return "Palindrome";
}
int main(void)
{
   printf("Enter a number: ");
   int n = scanf("%d", &n);
   printf("%s", PalindromeCheck(n));
   return 0;
}
```

Thank y'all and cheers from Brazil

(Feedback about readability and good practices would also be appreciated!!!!)

Comment: I'd start by [enabling elevated warnings](https://godbolt.org/z/qj59sWd8v), treating them as errors (because that is exactly what they are), and fixing those first. I would also suggest you learn what the functions you're calling actually do, and importantly, what they *return*. [scanf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) for example. I suspect you really won't want to use its *return value* as your input to a numeric palindrome check.

Comment: `int n = scanf("%d", &n);` is a problem because `scanf` returns the number of items converted, not the value of any of them. `printf("%s", PalindromeCheck(n));` is a problem because the function returns a single `char`, not a nul terminated string which is what the `%s` format specifier expects. Based on the code it should return a `const char*`.

Comment: The algorithm is also incorrect. Consider how it works with 121 as input once you fix the other issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all , function called **PalindromeCheck** , should return `char*` not `char` , return just `char` means that you want to return just one character like you are returning **c** or **b** or **a** , it's just like only one character not a full string , but returning a `char*` means that you are returning a pointer that points to a character or points to the first character in the string , that's how you can return string , other problem is in line `int n = scanf("%d", &n);` and then you pass **n** as argument to the function , please refer to [scanf() return value](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.3?topic=functions-scanf-read-data) , from the website they say :

> The scanf() function returns the number of fields that were successfully converted and assigned. The return value does not include fields that were read but not assigned.

so you only pass variable **n** as a parameter to `scanf()` function but not to assign it to the retun value of `scanf()` unless you wanted to do something with the
*the number of fields that were successfully converted and assigned*.
also you have to revise your logic , because the function will always be returning
"Not a Palindrome" , so I edited this condition `if (LastDigit != NumCopy % 10)` to  `if (NumCopy != 0 && LastDigit != NumCopy % 10)` to meet up with the definition of "Palindrome" and here is the full code :

```
    #include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

char* PalindromeCheck (int number){
    int NumCopy = number;
    while (NumCopy != 0){
        int LastDigit = NumCopy % 10;
        NumCopy = NumCopy / 10;
        if (NumCopy != 0 && LastDigit != NumCopy % 10){
            return "Not a Palindrome";
        }
    }
    return "Palindrome";
}
int main(void)
{
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("%s", PalindromeCheck(n));
    return 0;
}
```

and a picture of the output :

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the sadly broken algorithm, this should be it! hope this helps!!

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

char* PalindromeCheck (int number){
   char* toReturn = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * 17);
   int NumCopy = number;
   while (NumCopy != 0){
      int LastDigit = NumCopy % 10;
      NumCopy = NumCopy / 10;
      if (LastDigit != NumCopy % 10){
         strncpy(toReturn,"Not a Palindrome", 17);
         return toReturn;
      }
   }
   strncpy(toReturn,"Palindrome", 11);
   return toReturn;
}
int main(void)
{
   printf("Enter a number: ");
   int n;
   scanf("%d", &n);
   printf("%s\n", PalindromeCheck(n));
   return 0;
}
```